# What are host cellular factors?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, immunology

With respect to this paper:

[Global Analysis of Host-Pathogen
Interactions that Regulate
Early-Stage HIV-1 Replication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18854154)

What does the term "host cellular factors" mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally spoken, "host cellular factors" are proteins, receptors etc. of the host cell. In this case, they are important for the HIV infection. The authors write:

> Recently, a genome-wide siRNA analysis revealed over 250 host cellular
>   factors that influence HIV-1 infection.

This means gene silencing techniques where used to identify the host cellular factors which are important for the infection, you can find these results here: "[Identification of host proteins required for HIV infection through a functional genomic screen.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18187620)"
The overall goal is to identify proteins which are important for the function and infection of HIV to understand the interaction between virus and host cell better.